# How to express "map a linux command to each line in a file"?

Tags: linux, awk

Often I need to delete all the files not in a specific svn source tree. To get the list of all their file names, I use:

```
svn st | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}'
```

This command will give me a list of file names, one name per line. Then how can I express the idea of

```
for (each line in ${svn st | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}' )
    rm -f line
```

?

Comment: I'm not setup to test but maybe?...
svn st | grep ^? | awk '{print $2'} | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are so many people invoking `grep` in the pipeline and either using `bash`'s `for` loops or `xargs` on the back end when they have bloody **`awk`** right in the middle of things?

First let's get rid of the whimsical use of grep:

```
svn st | awk '/^?/ { print $2 }'
```

Since `awk` allows you to filter lines based on regular expressions, the use of grep is entirely unnecessary.  The regular expressions of `awk` aren't that different from `grep` (depending on which implementation of `awk` and which of `grep` you're using) so why add a whole new process and a whole new bottleneck in the pipeline?

From there you already have two choices that would be shorter and more readable:

```
# option 1
svn st | awk '/^?/ { print $2 }' | xargs rm -f

# option 2
rm -f $(svn st | awk '/^?/ { print $2 }')
```

Now that second option will only work if your file list doesn't exceed the maximum command line size, so I recommend the xargs version.

Or, perhaps even better, use `awk` again.

```
svn st | awk '/^?/ { system("rm -f $2") }'
```

This will be the functional equivalent of what you did above with the `for` loop.  It's grotesquely inefficient, seeing as it will execute rm once per file, but it's at least more readable than your `for` loop example.  It can be improved still farther, however.  I won't go into full details here, but will instead give you comments as clues as to what the final solution would look like.

```
svn st | awk 'BEGIN{ /*set up an array*/ }; /^?/ { /*add $2 to the array*/ }; END{ /*system("rm -f ...") safe chunks of the array*/}
```

OK, so that last one is a bit of a mouthful and too much to type off as a routine one-liner.  Since you have to "often" do this, however, it shouldn't be too bad to put this into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
BEGIN {
  /* set up your accumulator array */
}

/^?/ {
  /* add $2 to the array */
}

END {
  /* invoke system("rm -f") on safe chunks of the accumulator array */
}
```

Now your command line will be `svn st | myawkscript`.

Now I'll warn you I'm not equipped to check all this (since I avoid SVN and CVS like I avoid MS-DOS -- and for much the same reason).  You might have to monkey with the `#!` line in the script, for example, or with the regular expression you use to filter, but the general principle remains about the same.  And me personally?  I'd use `svn st | awk '/^?/ { print $2 }' | xargs rm -f` for something I do infrequently.  I'd only do the full script for something I do several times a week or more.

Comment: It seems the END expression will feed the list of file paths to "rm -f". In this case, would it suffer the problem that the list of arguments might exceed the maximum command line size?

Comment: Hence the reference to "safe chunks".  You put in a loop that grabs less than the maximum command line size at a time and issue `rm -f`.  `awk` is a general-purpose programming language.  It has loops and conditionals and calculations and all sorts of nifty stuff beyond pattern matching.

Answer (score 5):

Use xargs:

```
svn st | grep '^?' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

Note: In your command, you don't deal with files having whitespaces because of `{print $2}`.  You also have to be careful with `xargs` as it splits its input on whitespaces.  So it's safer to use the `-0` option if you have whitespaces in your filenames.

This is an example of a more correct xargs usage:

```
find -type f| tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 wc
```

Or, using find `-print0` option:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc
```

`xargs` is one of the most powerful UNIX tools.  I use it everyday.

Comment: The odd `'{print $2'}` parity there makes me nervous.  Should it be `'{print $2}'` or `{'print $2'}`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this with various drawbacks associated... One of the simpler ones is to use a `while read..` loop. Another way is to use a `for` loop and change `IFS` to `\n`, but that's a bit uglier without much of any benefit. You may see it done though, especially if they want word splitting on spaces.

```
git status | while read line; do
    echo "I'm an albatross! $line"
done
```

or, using process substitution (which gets rid of a subshell which can add [nasty complications](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024))

```
while read line; do
    echo "I'm an albatross! $line"
done <(git status)
```

There are caveats to this which may make things more complicated in specific situations. You should read `help read`, and [Bash FAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) contains lots of gory details.

Answer (score 0):

Use Command Substitution using back-ticks: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

In your case:

```
rm -f `svn st | grep ^? | awk '{print $2'}`
```

Comment: This will fail for long list of files.  xargs is safer as it invokes the command N times with appropriate sizing of argv.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is your friend:

```
svn st | awk '/^?/{print $2}'|xargs rm -rf
```